# FCM Push Notification not working in Flutter App for IOS devices

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

FCM Push Notification is not received when the Flutter app runs on IOS devices. Once the app goes in the background or is minimized, the Push notification works properly.

I have used firebase_messaging and flutter_local_notifications plugins for this.

```
  initialize() async {
   FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = await 
   SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   NotificationSettings settings = await messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    print('User granted permission');
  } else if (settings.authorizationStatus ==
    AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print('User granted provisional permission');
  } else {
    print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
  }

  messaging.getToken().then((token) {
    print("FCM TOKEN:- $token");
    sharedPreferences.setString("fcmToken", token.toString());
  });

  FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage event) {
    print("message received");
    print(event.notification!.body);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
      1,
      event.notification!.title.toString(),
      event.notification!.body.toString(),
      NotificationDetails(
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
          channel.id,
          channel.name,
          color: Colors.amber,
          playSound: true,
          icon: '@mipmap/ic_launcher',
        ),
      ));
  });
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((message) {
    print('Message clicked!');
  });
}
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Can you please share your code

Comment: @Mihirpatel I have added the code can you check

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you are not receiving while the app in foreground you need to add this

```
await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true, // Required to display a heads up notification
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
```

Comment: Hi @Abhijit Mazumder I need this notification code for IOS devices because on Android devices the push notification is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are listen notification in onMessage,You have added only android specification. please add IOS specification as well.

```
var iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics = const DarwinNotificationDetails(
presentBadge: true,
presentAlert: true,
presentSound: true,
interruptionLevel: InterruptionLevel.active);
```

Comment: Can you share the code for IOS?
Or else share some reference for IOS code

Comment: @RobertS I have added IOS specification please check